# How to plot .tif file colour coding onto the map using javascript?

Tags: javascript, react-js

I want to plot colour coding from .tif file into the map with the help of react-leaflet. How can this be done?
I am open for other better suggestions. My core goal is to display color coding given in geotiff file on an interactive map dynamically on a website.

Comment: It appears you already asked this over at Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71828390/how-to-plot-tif-file-colour-coding-onto-the-map-using-javascript) where it's a better fit. In the future, please don't [cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-que) to different Stack Exchange sites since that spreads answers out among them.

Comment: @dan , won't this question fit better here as compared to StackOverflow? As this is asking about web development?

Comment: @PHcoDer Questions about web development and [coding/programming](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are considered off-topic here.

Comment: @dan , Got it. So, this place is more for web administrators?

Comment: @PHcoDer You can review what's considered on-topic for this site here:  [What topics can I ask about here?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)